# Leiningen doesn't resolve my dependencies

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I want to translate a Maven dependency to Leiningen:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried:

```
(defproject gdata2 "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [com.google.api.client/google-api-client-parent "1.4.1-beta"]])
```

However this doesn't work since there is no jar in the Maven central repository, just a parent pom. Leiningen tries to find google-api-client-parent-1.4.1-beta.jar and fails.

How do I tell Leiningen to just look at the pom and resolve the transitive dependencies?

**Edit May 12**

It seems that the code I need is not in the standard Maven repositories. I have to add the Leiningen equivalent of:

```
<repository>
  <id>google-api-services</id>
  <url>http://mavenrepo.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg</url>
</repository>
```

And add google-api-services-tasks-1.0.0-beta.jar to the dependencies and then it is probably going to work. Will check and close this question when back from work :)

Answer (score 1):

That POM project doesn't define *any* dependency, just a `dependencyManagement` section. You probably want to depend on real libraries (e.g. JARs), which will in turn pull the whole dependency tree into the picture while solving your problem.

Comment: I tried depending on google-api-client which does have a jar and pulls in some but not all dependencies. I am looking for the jar that has the classes for the new Google Tasks lib (http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/tasks/index.html)

Comment: doesn't look like there's any artifact available yet, I checked both the [releases](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-releases/com/google/api/client/) and [snapshots](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/google-snapshots/com/google/api/client/) repos they're using. No google tasks.

Comment: The artifact is available. See the link (after the Edit from May 12th) in the original question.

Comment: you're right, I just looked at the `distributionManagement` section of the parent and assumed I knew the right place to peek at :-)